# How to update a forms text fields when a drop gets updated using php

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form in a php page that I want to have updated as the drop down is changed. Here is the code for the form:

```
<form action="AdminPage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="version" />
    <label><strong>Name:</strong></label>
    <select id="WebName" name="Name">
        <option value="ReportDashboard">ReportDashboard</option>
        <option value="ReportDashboard Dev"<?php if(strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],"dev/FrontierReports",1) > 0){echo " selected='selected'";}?>>ReportDashboard Dev</option>
        <option value="ReportDashboard Testing"<?php if(strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],"dev/Testing",1) > 0){echo " selected='selected'";}?>>ReportDashboard Testing</option>
    </select><p></p>
    <label><strong>Version Number: </strong></label>
    <input id="VersionNumber" type="text" name="VersionNumber" value="<?php echo $VersionNumber['VersionNo']; ?>" /><p></p>
    <label><strong>Version Type:</strong></label>
    <select id="Type" name="VersionType">
        <option value="1">Major</option>
        <option value="2">Minor</option>
        <option value="3" selected="selected">Bug</option>
    </select><p></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="VersionNumberCheck" value="<?php echo $VersionNumber['VersionNo']; ?>" />
    <label><strong>Notes</strong></label>
    <input id="Notes" type="text" name="Notes" value="<?php echo $ReleaseNotes['ReleaseNotes']; ?>" />
    <p><input class="Pointer" type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Version" /></p>
    <p><input id="VersionSubmit" class="Pointer" type="button" name="VersionSubmit" value="Current Notes" /></p>
</form>
```

Currently, the form gets its values for the 2 text fields (`VersionNumber` and `Notes`) from outside the form. I would like to have them be obtained as the form is created based on what the first drop down (`Name`) has selected and then update if that drop down gets changed.

I thought of adding some PHP to the form to help, but it doesn't work. Here is what I tried:

```
<form action="AdminPage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="version" />
    <label><strong>Name:</strong></label>
    <select id="WebName" name="Name">
        <option value="ReportDashboard">ReportDashboard</option>
        <option value="ReportDashboard Dev"<?php if(strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],"dev/FrontierReports",1) > 0){echo " selected='selected'";}?>>ReportDashboard Dev</option>
        <option value="ReportDashboard Testing"<?php if(strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],"dev/Testing",1) > 0){echo " selected='selected'";}?>>ReportDashboard Testing</option>
    </select><p></p>
    <?php 
        $Vsql = "select top 1 VersionNo,ReleaseNotes from pmdb.Version where Name = 'ReportDashboard' order by name,VersionNo desc";
        $GetVersion = $conn->query($Vsql);
        $VersionNumber = $GetVersion->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    ?>
    <label><strong>Version Number: </strong></label>
    <input id="VersionNumber" type="text" name="VersionNumber" value="<?php echo $VersionNumber['VersionNo']; ?>" /><p></p>
    <label><strong>Version Type:</strong></label>
    <select id="Type" name="VersionType">
        <option value="1">Major</option>
        <option value="2">Minor</option>
        <option value="3" selected="selected">Bug</option>
    </select><p></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="VersionNumberCheck" value="<?php echo $VersionNumber['VersionNo']; ?>" />
    <label><strong>Notes</strong></label>
    <input id="Notes" type="text" name="Notes" value="<?php echo $ReleaseNotes['ReleaseNotes']; ?>" />
    <p><input class="Pointer" type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Version" /></p>
    <p><input id="VersionSubmit" class="Pointer" type="button" name="VersionSubmit" value="Current Notes" /></p>
</form>
```

I don't know how to capture what is in the drop down to change the SQL that is pulling the data. I thought of possibly just pulling all of the rows back and then doing a search against it once the form is built, but I still don't know how to capture when the drop down changes and then update the 2 text boxes.

**UPDATE**

I now have a new file named `UpdateAdminVersion.php` this is what is has:

```
$Vsql = "select top 1 VersionNo,ReleaseNotes from pmdb.Version where Name = 'ReportDashboard' order by name,VersionNo desc";
$GetVersion = $conn->query($Vsql);
$VersionNumber = $GetVersion->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$data = $VersionNumber;
echo json_encode($data);
```

I also added the following script to the previous file with the form:

```
$("#WebName").change(function ()
{
    $.post("UpdateAdminVersion.php",
    {
        parameter1: "ReportDashboard Dev",
        parameter2: $("#VersionNumber").val()
    },
    function (data, status)
    {
        aconsole.log(data)
        $("#Notes").val(data);
    });
});
```

I must still be missing something because nothing happens when I change the drop down.

**UPDATE 2**

I've changed the `script` to this:

```
$("#WebName").change(function ()
{
    $.post("UpdateAdminVersion.php",
    {
        WebName: $('#WebName').val(),
        VersionNumber: $("#VersionNumber").text()
    },
    function (data, status)
    {
        console.log(data)
        $("#Notes").val(data);
        success: alert ("Number 2 is successful!");
    });
    success: alert ("Number 1 is successful! \n" + WebName + "\n" + VersionNumber);
});
```

I get the `alert` *Number 1 is successful!*, but the `WebName` and `VersionNumber` variables return `[object HTMLSelectElement]` and `[objectHTMLInputElement]` respectively. How do I return the actual values?

And how do I use them in the `UpdateAdminVersion.php` file?

Answer (score 0):

For starters you can use [jqueryUI Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) to feed Select tag with options.

Then use  onchange event to capture dropdown changes.

```
<select onchange="myFunction()">
```

when event is triggered retreive data from db using Ajax, on success modify your form fields accordingly.

Look at this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v88gjd8m/1/) give your own parameters, should work.

Comment: This looks promising. It'll take me a while to implement though.

Comment: Look at the fiddle should give you some idea. Which part is tricky for you?

Comment: Looking at the fiddle, I'll need a separate file that will pull back the data from my DB? and then the function will query it each time the drop down is changed?

Comment: Exacly. Your new PHP file should return Json. If this is new you'll need this in your PHP file:  `header("Content-type:application/json"); echo json_encode($data);`

Comment: I made an update to the question. I am still missing something. Or, more likely, not understanding something.

Comment: Few things: $data variable is not mandatory, parameter1,parameter2... these are also optional, those are PHP -s $_POST["parameter1"] kinda data. you don't have Header before echo json_encode($data), at js you have aconsole (should be console). Just test things untill you get final results, I mean just do alert("dsadsda") at success or something to be sure it works.

Comment: I see, how would I use the `parameter` in the new file? I'm guessing that is what they are for?

Comment: I added another update. I got the alert to work, but I'm not sure how to return the actual value in the drop down and I'm not sure how to use that value in the `UpdateAdminVersion.php` file.